# Gatsbyjs develop LOCAL HOST loads slow, 15 minutes slow

Tags: localhost, gatsby, webpack-hmr

So, suddenly, gatsby develop gives me success in the VStudioCode console but, entering local host 8000 in the browser, the page loads my page SUPER SLOW! The background image of the site appears but the content doesn't. I'm too much of a beginner to understand how this is happening.

I attached a picture to show the chrome dev Tools network. It's crazy. 15 minutes for the webpack_hmr, even 1.5hrs at one point. I didn't have to wait that long but it shows it.

This is way beyond my skill level. The site is still super small, only pulling two pages from contentful cms.

What maybe caused this? No idea.

What did I do?

1. tried installing @hot-loader/react-dom because my chrome console said it couldn't detect react-dom/hot loader
2. gatsby clean to clean cache and public folder

Why would webpack_hmr be taking so long? What are these socket and polling things in the network I see so much of?

I'd appreciate any ideas or suggestions, i'm at such a complete loss.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkYKI.jpg)

Comment: I've just encountered the same issue.. also at a complete loss. Did you happen to find a solution?

Comment: @ejscribner I never did really. It went away and I'm not sure why. One thing I did was just update all the packages. It seemed to go away after that. So I'd start there. Then I'd check to see how you're loading in your data. Maybe you've created a weird code scenario that is causing the delay. Like loading something that's too large in size or something. Sorry I can't be more help

Comment: thanks for responding!! I actually ended up figuring out the issue-- it was a Data Loss Prevention agent that had just been remotely installed by my employer. I don’t really understand why, and it took a lot of convincing with the IT department, but finally uninstalling this agent that runs in the background fixed it. Still unsure why it only affected Node processes.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a lot of different reasons of it. I'll tell you about my case.

I'm using Gatsby together with WAMP backend. I had a huge `access.log` file on my local Apache server (> 14 MB). I've cleaned `access.log` and `error.log` files and the problem has gone.

PS. My Apache log files are here: `c:\Apache\Apache2.2\logs\`